# Is querying reverse foreign keys lazy?

Tags: python, django

I need to check if user has at least one connected product of many types that we have in a system. I'm trying to make it more efficient so I added any() and made a generator for connection check. But I wonder if it still will query all reverse relationships and evaluate them. User can have a lot of products of each type.

My code:

```
def has_connected_product(self):
    def check_product_set_on_connected(product_sets):
        for product_set in product_sets:
            if product_set.model.__name__ == 'ShopifyProduct':
                yield product_set.exclude(shopify_id__isnull=True).exclude(shopify_id=0).exists()
            else:
                yield product_set.exclude(source_id__isnull=True).exclude(source_id=0).exists()

    return any(check_product_set_on_connected([
        self.user.shopifyproduct_set,
        self.user.commercehqproduct_set,
        self.user.wooproduct_set,
        self.user.ebayproduct_set,
        self.user.fbproduct_set,
        self.user.googleproduct_set,
        self.user.gearbubbleproduct_set,
        self.user.groovekartproduct_set,
        self.user.bigcommerceproduct_set,
    ]))
```

Comment: Can You show code written in `any()`.

Comment: @ManojKamble I show it in my code example. It's returned from this method